# Android Linkedin init no callback trigger

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I am using the new Linkedin API (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)
I've done the imports and the project runs without crashing.

This is my MainActivity implemetation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Store a reference to the current activity
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Activity thisActivity = this;

    // Build the list of member required permissions
    List<String> scope = new ArrayList<String>();
    scope.add("r_basicprofile");
    scope.add("w_share");

    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(thisActivity, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            // Authentication was successful.  You can now do
            // other calls with the SDK.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAuthSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("nitai", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
            // Handle authentication errors
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAuthError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("nitai", "fail");

        }


    }, true);
}

// Build the list of member permissions our LinkedIn session requires
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE);
}
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    }
```

The problem is that neither of the callbacks are triggered (OAuthSuccess / OAuthError).

Comment: anything interesting in logcat?

Comment: I found the answer. had to implement this line:     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: the above method has to be implemented in the activity which triggered the fragment of authentication , if being used. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your Activity it will work for you

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); }
```